# Store 366 names and ages into an array(s) and return values depending on the current date

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a hard time trying to code this logic. I would need to store 366 names and ages to an array and find returned values depending on the current date. The below code snippet would give you a better idea what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$usernames = array(“John”,”April”); // 366 of them
$userages = array(“24”,”32”); //366 of them

//returns 0 to 365 Jan 1 = 0 
$today = date(“z”);

$myusername =  $usernames[$today];
$myage = $age[$today];
```

I'm not sure if I am approaching this correctly. I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you